Авто масштабирование Label фреймворк kivy
Python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import os

class Form(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        with open('файл', 'r') as file:
            text = file.read()
        ReadForm = Label(text = text, font_size = 20, size_hint_x = 1, text_size = (720, None))
        self.add_widget(ReadForm)

class Reader(App):
    def build(self):
        read = Form()
        return read

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Reader().run()

Итак, вот наш код ↑ (пока что пример простейшей читалки)
В классе ReadForm я все не могу додуматься, как мне реализовать авто изменение size_hint_y в Label (ReadForm), в зависимости от размера входящего текста. Данный код будет рассчитываться на Андроид, так что размеры экрана будут считаться как 720 по Х и 1600 по У. Текст не должен будет выходить за рамки виджета по горизонтали. Буду благодарен будь кто поможет найти решение
